# What is the difference between implode() & join()

Tags: php

What is the difference between `implode()` & `join()` as both work the same way.

```
<?php
    $array = array(1,2,3);
    
    echo join(",", $array); // output 1,2,3
    echo implode(",", $array); // output 1,2,3
?>
```

Is there is any advantage of using one over another?

Comment: So i can use any of the method. There is no such issue as if `JOIN` will convert an array into sting much faster than the other and vice versa?

Comment: yes `JOIN` is faster, it has 3 less letters ;)

Comment: Use 'join' as it is more common in most other programming languages and therefore makes your code more readable. There are no performance advantages or disadvantages either way, so go with comprehensibility. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36974284/467386

Comment: `implode` is highlighted by Notepad++ `join` isn't ;)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

They are aliases of each other. They should theoretically work exactly the same. Although, using explode/implode has been shown to increase the awesomeness of your code by 10%

Comment: I think its more than just 10%

Comment: yay, `implode` is orthodox. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ec974c439724e8b4151412eaa0caba5aec5e1c49/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L2759-L2760

Comment: For python programmers join is more standard.

Comment: I believe it's 11.78%

Comment: implode/explode = programmer's **SWAG**;

Comment: I just saw `join` for the first time in php, and I must say, I completely lost some coding respect for the author of that code!

Comment: `MichaelBay::explode('things')`

Comment: How to program 101, just use implode instead of join. join is for lame people, but implode is another story.

Comment: Has probably gone up to around 20% in 2021.

Answer (score 24):

**Join**: Join is an Alias of implode().

Example:

```
<?php
$arr = array('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');
$str = join(",", $arr);
echo $str; 
?>
```

> Output: Test1,Test2,Test3.

**Implode**: implode Returns a string from array elements.

Example:

```
<?php
$arr = array('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');
$str = implode(",", $arr);
echo $str; 
?>
```

> Output: Test1,Test2,Test3.

**UPDATE:**

I tested them in Benchmark and they are same in speed. There is no difference between them.

Comment: @MarkBaker, You are right. I test it now with a lot of array, and implode and join show the same time to execute. I was wrong, and I edit my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any differences between question and your answer ?

Comment: This should be the correct answer. join appends the delimiter to the last element while implode doesn't.

Comment: @AdamAzad, you are mistaken, `join` does NOT append the delimiter to the last element

Answer (score 20):

`join()` is an alias for `implode()`, so `implode` is theoretically more "PHP native" though there is absolutely no performance increase to be gained by using it.

On the other hand, `join()` is found in, amongst other languages, Perl, Python and ECMAScript (including JavaScript) and so is much more portable in terms of comprehensibility to a wider audience of programmers.

So although `explode` and `implode` are unarguably way more dramatic-sounding, I would vote for `join` as a more universal way to express the concatenation of every value of an array into a string.

Answer (score 5):

Can't think of any.  The one is an alias of the other.  They both combine array elements into a string.

Answer (score -1):

In short the reality is that in php,  join() and implode() methods function the same way.

One can be interchanged for the other as they work in the same way.

Comment: What does this add to the thread? This is basically the same as the accepted answer.