# Pass an array as parameters to SQL procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have SQL procedure in which I'm using an IN statment. It goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id IN('1','2','12','14')
```

What I need to do is pass the values in to the IN statment as parameter which is an array in php, rather than hard-coded. How can I do that?

Comment: Simply replace your single quote encapsulates variables with a reference to the array key you want to use I.e. $myarray[0]

Answer (score 3):

You can implode on this case:

```
$array = array('1','2','12','14');
$ids = "'".implode("','", $array) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `costumers` WHERE `id` IN($ids)";
echo $sql;
// SELECT * FROM `costumers` WHERE `id` IN('1','2','12','14')
```

or if you do not want any quotes:

```
$ids = implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: this helped, thank you. Had to use ids array like this though: ".$ids."

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP function [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$array = array("1","2","12","14");

$query = "SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id IN(".implode(', ',$array).")"
```

Answer (score 1):

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is the right function, but you also must pay attention to the type of the data.

If the field is numeric, it is simple:

```
$values = array(1. 2, 5);
$queryPattern = 'SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id IN(%s)';
$query = sprintf($queryPattern, implode(', ',$values));
```

But if it's a string, you must play with single and double quotes:

```
$values = array("foo","bar","baz");
$queryPattern = 'SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id IN("%s")';
$query = sprintf($queryPattern, implode('", "',$values));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$array = array('1','2','12','14');

SELECT * FROM `costumers` WHERE `id` IN('{$array}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try imploding the php into an array, and then interpolating that string into the SQL statement:

```
$arr = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$string = implode(", ", $arr);

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id in ($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

use PHP's `join` function to join the values of an array.

```
$arr = array(1,2,12,14);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id IN(" . join($arr, ',') . ")";
```

Comment: `join` and `implode` are actually the same, I prefer `join`, but others here seem to prefer implode.  (What's the difference? -[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914008/what-is-the-difference-between-implode-join)

Comment: I prefer `implode` to easily distinguish it from SQL `JOIN` and it is also easier to recognize as the complementary function of `explode`.

Comment: A valid reason @rink.attendant.6. The reason for my preference is just that `join` is the more common name for this function in other languages (SQL excluded), like C#, Perl, Python, Java, Javascript, etc. -- implode/explode is almost unique to PHP.